# How to solve this summation related to random walks model for first arrival?

Tags: probability, summation, random-walk, z-transform

I want to solve this summation which is given as :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sum_{k=1}^nv_{2k}u_{2n-2k})z^{2n}$$
note that $v_{2k}$ is the first arrival to origin in $2k$ steps and $u_{2n-2k}$ is the arrival to the origin, and $z$ represent the z-transform which is done to find the moment generating function.
I substitute $n-k=m$ and got:
$$\sum_{m=1-k}^{\infty}u_{2m}z^{2m}\sum_{k=1}^{m+k}v_{2k}z^{2k}$$
I do not know how to move from here to the answer, which is:
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}u_{2m}z^{2m}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}v_{2k}z^{2k}=U(z)V(z)$$
what are the steps that I can't think about
**This looks like convolution but here the first summation is dependent on the second one!!!**

PS: As per the comment by Greg Martin, I assume that the values of outer index $m=n-k$ can vary from $0$ to $\infty$. However for inner integral taking suppose $m=0$ the values can vary from ($k=n-m$), i.e., $1$ to $\infty$, similarly for $m=1$ $k=[0,\infty]$ which is the integer range. Is this how one should approach this. Cn we simply make two of the summations independent of one another like this? Am I correct?

Comment: Note that in your second sum after the substitution, the bounds $\sum_{k=1}^{m+k}$ can't be correct—the index of summation is $k$, which can't be referenced in the bounds of summation. Indeed there can't be a $k$ in the outer summation's bounds either since $k$ doesn't exist outside the inner sum. When figuring out the new bounds, you want to answer the questions: (1) what are all possible integer values of the outer index $m$? (2) For each value of $m$, what are all possible values of $k$ (perhaps in terms of $m$)?

Comment: @Greg Martin Can you please check my updated question, wherein I have tried the approach you have mentioned. Am I correct?

Comment: I believe you're correct. We didn't "make" the summations independent; it turned out, once we did the reindexing correctly, that they happened to become independent.